# Analytic function mapping inside the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on this problem which appears to be a [preliminary exam question in UTexas.](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/academics/graduate/prelims/old_exams/2012_08_Analysis_B.pdf)

> Assume that $f$ is analytic outside the closed unit disk and $ |f(z)| <1$ in this region. Prove that $|f'(2)| \leq \frac{1}{3}$

I can prove that $|f'(2)| < 1$ but the upper bound $1/3$ is very hard to get. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(z):=f(1/z)$ then $g$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ and $g( \mathbb{D})\subseteq \mathbb{D}$.

Then we can apply the [Schwarz–Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem) (a variant of [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma)): for all $z\in \mathbb{D}$,
$$|g'(z)|\leq \frac{1-|g(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}.$$
Since $g'(z)=f'(1/z)\cdot(-1/z^2)$, it follows that
$$|f'(1/z)|\leq \frac{(1-|f(1/z)|^2)\cdot|z|^2}{1-|z|^2}.$$
Now for $z=1/2$, we finally obtain
$$|f'(2)|\leq \frac{(1-|f(2)|^2)\cdot|1/2|^2}{1-|1/2|^2}=\frac{1-|f(2)|^2}{3}\leq \frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: It's the first time I see Schwarz–Pick theorem, it is indeed helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @iamvegan Usually the Schwarz–Pick theorem is not covered by standard courses in complex analysis. However it is nice result about the rigidity of holomorphic functions.

Comment: Very interesting (I upvote). A little thought: if this is the only way to answer to a "preliminary entrance exam question to UTexas", what extraordinary level have its students !